# ccny_rgbd Communication with keyframe_mapper_node fails after first service call

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ccny-rgbd, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ros fuerte and I am running into this issue where the service call to the keyframe_mapper_nodes fails after the first call, as in every call after the first call fails. The first call succeeds. The error that I get for the calls after the first call are

```
ERROR: Unable to communicate with service [/solve_graph], address [rospc: // localhost:43886]
```

Sometimes I also get

```
ERROR: transport error compleing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

The last two line in the service log says

```
/use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
signal_shutdown [atexit]
atexit
```

With the exact same setup I have got it all working twice. So it randomly works but I dont know why this is happening. I am using the openni driver packages in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87696/ccny_rgbd-communication-with-keyframe_mapper_node-fails-after-first-service-call/) by [avalada](https://answers.ros.org/users/6686/avalada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this has got to do something with issue 22 posted on github, which says is fixed.  When there are very low amount of keyframes, if you call the generate_graph call, the keyframe_mapper node crashes. If you move the kinect enough to get a lot of keyframes, then service call goes through fine.

---

Originally posted by [avalada](https://answers.ros.org/users/6686/avalada/) with karma: 31 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0